# How should I pronounce double consonant in a Sanskrit word?

Tags: sanskrit

The visarga in रामः शेते is facing Sh so it should change to Sh, right? And we get the one word रामश्शेते Raamashshete, but I am not sure how it should be pronounced. Should the dobule Sh be mingled and pronounced the Raamashshete as Raamashete like the word soccer or kissing in English? Or should I pronounce Raammash and then Shete, Raamash'Shete ike I am pronouncing two words?

Comment: Support the creation of a Sanskrit stackexchange (currently in definition phase) here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language

Comment: There is no audible doubling of the cc in "soccer" or the ss in "kissing". It is purely orthographic.

Comment: @fdb: In English consonant doubling is purely orthographic. In Sanskrit double consonants are pronounced as geminates. The question arises because the rules of Sanskrit morphophonemics (_sandhi_) are complex and occasionally produce situations where the doubling may be considered artificial.

Comment: @jlawler. We are (as usual) in complete agreement.

Comment: It need to be pronounced the way it is written. If its written as रामः शेते you need to pronounce रामः शेते. If its रामश्शेते than you need to say रामश्शेते. Also its placement in sentence would effect the pronunciation of visargas

Answer (score 4):

The changing of visarga to श् is optional. Therefore the words can be

> रामश् शेते

or

> रामः शेते

From the above, there are two ways to pronounce these combination of words. A सन्धिः is performed in `संहिता` (closely uttering letters) and when it happens, you should pronounce it as `RamaShShete`. There should certainly be a doubling of the `Sh` and it closely resembles Sh in *shake*.

In the absence of `संहिता` the words रामः and शेते are pronounced separately, so the visarga in रामः is clearly audible, followed by a small gap (at least 1 second) and the word `शेते`

Comment: So performing in संहिता, should Raamashshete pronounced as Rammash-Shete, fully pronouncing two Sh? And also should Visarga Sandhi rules applied when chanting Vedid mantras?

Comment: Like should I chant it Raamash and then Shete or Raamashete as if there's only one sh in the word. This is very confusing to me because I know that Raamashshete is one word after visarga rule is applied, but it's kind of hard to pronounce two Sh straight without pausing for 0.5 second..

Comment: रामश्शेते can never be one word. रामश् and शेते remain two distinct words despite the सन्धिः In संहिता both the श् should be pronounced, which equates to them being doubled. In Vedic chanting, संहिता is applied and therefore, sandhi rules must be applied. If you chant रामश्शेते it appears as though there is just one word and there will be no observable gap/pause when you utter it. However, note that they are two separate words because a samasa (compound) cannot be formed between a verb and a noun.